Installation process of Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't start in VirtualBox
The installation process of Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't start in VirtualBox.

Can I fix this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
